# node.js read a text file and write modify strings. (each line has a word order)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to read a large file from a thousand lines. Each line has the words and phrases.

So if the file is like this:

```
key, phrase, combination of words, phrase, combination of keys, word
phrase, word
key, words, phrase, combination of keys, combination of words
combination of keys
words, phrase, combination of keys
```

In line combination or single words separated by commas

```
.split(",")
```

1. How to write to file the combination of the first four words or less in string?
2. How not to write to file strings without commas?

Desired result modify:

```
key, phrase, combination of words, phrase
phrase, word
key, words, phrase, combination of keys
words, phrase, combination of keys
```

Comment: Are you just trying to create a string from that file of words? I.e. is the expected/desired result from that file to have a string with value `key, phrase combinations of words, phrase`?

Comment: Yes. Desired result from that file to have a string with value  'key, phrase, combinations of words, phrase'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample doing what you asked :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var output;
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/file')
});

var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.txt');


lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    var array = line.split(',');
    var toWrite = "";

    if (array.length <= 4) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            toWrite += array[i] + ",";
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            toWrite += array[i] + ",";
        }
    }

    toWrite = toWrite.slice(0,-1);
    toWrite += "\r\n";

    output.write(toWrite)

});
```

You can use `readline` from npm to read each line of the file, and then with a simple algorithm, loop over the words and add them to a string that will be added to the output file.